# @PostMapping to other microservices with Feign and Eureka

Tags: java, spring, microservices, netflix-eureka, feign

I'm building a microservice architecture with Spring Framework, Feign and Eureka.

- Shop works as an API Gateway, realised with Zuul (no database)
- Each microservice has its own h2 database.
- The CustomerService can call cart mappings with Feign

**Example:** I have a "Shop" and want to create a customer with a cart in one method in the service itself.

How can I call methods in the ShopService, to manage the other Services without having relationships to the other services? Please let me know if you need code examples.

**CustomerController.java:**

```
@ComponentScan
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    final Customer2CartConnectorRequester customer2CartConnectorRequester;
    final Customer2OrderConnectorRequester customer2OrderConnectorRequester;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerJpaRepository customerJpaRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(Customer2CartConnectorRequester customer2CartConnectorRequester,
            Customer2OrderConnectorRequester customer2OrderConnectorRequester) {
        this.customer2CartConnectorRequester = customer2CartConnectorRequester;
        this.customer2OrderConnectorRequester = customer2OrderConnectorRequester;

    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<CustomerEntity> getCustomers() {

        return customerJpaRepository.findAll();
    }


    @RequestMapping("/{customerId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<CustomerEntity> getCustomer(@PathVariable("customerId") int customerId) {

        return customerJpaRepository.findById(customerId);
    }

    // Client to Server
    // POST über z.B. Postman Client
    @PostMapping("/customer")
    public CustomerEntity addCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerEntity customerEntity) {

        customerJpaRepository.save(customerEntity);

        return customerEntity;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("customer/{customerId}")
    public String deleteCustomer(@PathVariable int customerId) {

        CustomerEntity a = customerJpaRepository.getOne(customerId);
        customerJpaRepository.delete(a);

        return "deleted";
    }

    @PutMapping("/customer")
    public CustomerEntity updateCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerEntity customerEntity) {

        customerJpaRepository.save(customerEntity);

        return customerEntity;
    }

    /// CONNECTOR REQUESTER ///

    @GetMapping("/cart")
    public List<?> getCart() {
        return customer2CartConnectorRequester.getCart();
    }

    @GetMapping("/orders")
    public List<?> getOrders() {
        return customer2OrderConnectorRequester.getOrders();
    }

}
```

**Update:**
I tried using a POST-Method to send data via Postman Client like this, but it seems like there is still something wrong:

**Shop2CustomerConnectorRequester:**

```
@FeignClient("customermicroservice")
public interface Shop2CustomerConnectorRequester {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createCustomer(Map<String, ?> queryMap);
}
```

**ShopController:**

```
@ComponentScan
@RestController
public class ShopController {

    final Shop2CustomerConnectorRequester shop2CustomerConnectorRequester;

    @Autowired
    private ShopJpaRepository shopJpaRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ShopController(Shop2CustomerConnectorRequester shop2CustomerConnectorRequester) {
        this.shop2CustomerConnectorRequester = shop2CustomerConnectorRequester;

    }

    @GetMapping("/customer")
    public  ResponseEntity<String> createCustomer(Map<String, ?> queryMap) {
        return shop2CustomerConnectorRequester.createCustomer(queryMap);
    }


}
```